# is i >= elementData.length in ArrayList::iterator redundant?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

This is the next method of ArrayList::Itr

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

It contains a if statement:

```
if (i >= elementData.length)
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

I think It's rarely that condition `i >= elementData.length` happen, unless user invoke trimToSize method. And I think the if statement is redundant, because checkForComodification can handle everything.
Am I right?

Comment: I'm thinking that you do NOT mean "abundant" ... because it doesn't make sense.  Do you mean "redundant"?

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much.

Comment: *"Am I right?"* No, because you don't have the guarantee, that one will not manipulate the content after `checkForComodification` call, but before `if (i >= elementData.length)`. You will find a lot of cases, when you google for *"java ConcurrentModificationException iterator"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. If another thread is used such that the `ArrayList`'s `trimTosize` was used *after* the

```
checkForComodification();
```

...but *before* the

```
Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
```

`ArrayList.this.elementData` may have been changed (received a new array reference) in the interim. So it's correct and necessary to check that the index is valid in the array *after* grabbing `ArrayList.this.elementData` into a local variable (`elementData`). After the code has done that, it has a local reference to the array it will look in (`elementData`) and a local variable for the index `i`). The code is necessary at that point in order to throw the correct exception (`ConcurrentModificationException`) rather than `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` if a change to `ArrayList.this.elementData` before the code grabbed it made the index invalid.

E.g., note the `**` lines:

```
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;                                    // ***
        if (i >= size)                                     // ***
            throw new NoSuchElementException();            // ***
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData; // ***
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
```

The other thread could come in there. It's only once we have our own reference to the array we'll use (once the last `**` line is done) that we know the reference won't change (as it's local).

Comment: I think your answer is partially correct. It's true that ArrayIndexOutOfBounds might happen without "i >= elementData.length" check. But, this check can not guarantee that ArrayIndexOutOfBounds will never happen, because elementData size might also be changed after "cursor = i + 1;", before "return" by another thread. So, I think the check for length is meaningless. Isn't it?

Comment: @expoter: No, it cannot be. The content of an array is mutable, but the array's length is not. As of the `Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;` line I pointed out, we know that our local `elementData` variable cannot refer to a different array between `if (i >= elementData.length)` and `return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];` We also know that `i` cannot be changed by another thread. Prior to that line, though, `ArrayList.this.elementData` **can** be changed to point to a different array. So the check is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean "redundant" not "abundant", then no it isn't.

There is a small (tiny) window *after* the call to `checkForComodification()` in which the array's size could be changed because another thread has resized the `ArrayList`.  The chances of this happening is very small, but if this check wasn't there, the `next()` call might throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException`.

---

The flipside is that the `next()` code is not guaranteed to detect all concurrent modifications.  If some other thread managed to add an element to the list after the `checkForComodification()` call, that modification would go undetected.